# CakePHP : Send Value To Model Function

Tags: cakephp, user-defined-functions, cakephp-2.2

My idea like this. I create a function at Model like this.

```
public function status($id = null)
{
$conditions = array('Transaction.catalogue_id' => $id);
$status = $this->find('first',array('conditions' => $conditions, 'fields' => array('Transaction.status'),'order' => array('Transaction.id' => 'desc'))
  );
return $status['Transaction']['status'];
}
```

How i send the value of $id from this loop?

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="all">
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Author</th>
          <th>ISBN</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Availability</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php $count = 1;?>
      <tbody>  
      <?php foreach ($Catalogue as $Catalogue): ?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $count++; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($Catalogue['Catalogue']['title'],array('controller' => 'transactions', 'action' => 'view',$Catalogue['Catalogue']['id']),array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'ajax')); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $Catalogue['Catalogue']['author']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $Catalogue['Catalogue']['isbn']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $Catalogue['Location']['rack']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $this->getstatus($Catalogue['Catalogue']['id'])</td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
      <?php unset($Catalogue); ?>
  </table>
```

Can we do $this->getstatus($Catalogue['Catalogue']['id'])?

Comment: PS: that's not very good coding. you do not check if the return value is actually filled. It the id was invalid you would trigger undefined index errors... `if (!$status) { return false; }` etc should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Misread the question apologies:
Yes you can access functions (inside controllers) from the view page using the requestAction
      $this->requestAction('controllerName/actionName/'.$parameter);

So in your case:

```
 $this->requestAction('status/' .$Catalogue['Catalogue']['id']);
```

==========================================

I'll leave my original (wrong) answer in, incase it's helpful in someway :)

You need to set the value in the controller so you can call it up on your view pages.

```
 $this->set('status', $status);
```

Then on your view page you can use
     echo $status

Although you don't need it in your example you can also use CakePHP's copmact function, allowing yo to create multiple variables.
     $this->set(compact('var1','var2','var5'));
would all become availabe in the view as:

```
 echo $var1.$var2.$var3;
```

Comment: sorry.can you give example of controller.i new in cakephp. i don't get what you write

Answer (score 0):

You should be using your Model in CakePHP to define the relationship between Catalogue and Transaction. Although what you are attempting is possible, it's a lot more effort than it needs to be. One or two lines of code (providing you have key'd your tables correctly) and Cake will do the rest for you. Pretty neat, yes? Yes.

In your Catalogue.php Model file, define a hasOne relationship with Transaction. Use ORDER to get the latest record...

```
class Catalogue extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Catalogue';

    public $hasOne = array(
       'Transaction' => array(
           'className'    => 'Transaction'
           'order'        => 'Transaction.id DESC'
       )
    );
}
```

And then in your view, instead of

```
<td><?php echo $Catalogue['Catalogue']['id'];?></td>
```

just do

```
<td><?php echo $Catalogue['Transaction']['status'];?></td>
```

You can read more about relationships in CakePHP in the [manual here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

Comment: i want to get a latest transaction from table transaction.Catalogue hasMany transaction

Comment: hasOne will only return one record, so add ORDER to it to get the last record and there you have it. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: i try above code. it shows transaction status. but the problem is the data repeating.

Comment: Got an example of what is repeating exactly?

Comment: if a catalogue has 3 transaction. it shows, 3 catalogue details with diffent status

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the model as a variable to the view like this:

```
public function action() {
    ...
    $this->set('Catalogue', $this->Catalogue);
}
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
<td><?php echo $Catalogue->getstatus($catalogue['Catalogue']['id'])?></td>
```

But you should be doing this on the model. Trying to get the entire list of items along with its status.